# Soap webservice: alert posting Mantas error

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications, oracle11g

I have a bug I have been trying to solve for weeks. I am running a SOAP webservice and I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to execute Alert processing step : AssignAlert
```

as you can see below on the SOAP message below. This is from an Oracle Mantas application, but it may be a more generic error message. Thank you in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://namespaces.mantas.com">ns1:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Failed to execute Alert processing step : AssignAlert</faultstring>
      <faultactor>/services/AlertManagementService</faultactor>
      <detail>
        <PostAlertFault>
          <errorCode>170364</errorCode>
          <errorMessage>Failed to execute Alert processing step : AssignAlert</errorMessage>
          <errorDescription>java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException</errorDescription>
        </PostAlertFault>
        <ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">myhostname</ns2:hostname>
      </detail>
    </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```